# Jquery Parsing an XML file outputs a blank table

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I'm trying to create a table by parsing an XML file with jquery. The XML file looks like this...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>
<E1TC NAME='R584211WXB' VERSION='a'>
<TextLine1>
    <1>2011/11/06</1>
    <2>5748283</2>
    <3>10.9300</3>
    <4>4049027</4>
    <5>7.7000</5>
    <6>42799422</6>
    <7>81.3800</7>
    <8>52596733</8>
</TextLine1>
<TextLine1>
...
</TextLine1>
</E1TC>
```

My jquery function looks like this

```
        // Build an HTML string
        myHTMLOutput = '';
        myHTMLOutput += '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        myHTMLOutput += '<th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th>';

        // Run the function for each TextLine1 tag in the XML file
        $('TextLine1',xml).each(function(i)
        {
            d1 = $(this).find("1").text();
            d2 = $(this).find("2").text();
            d3 = $(this).find("3").text();
            d4 = $(this).find("4").text();
            d5 = $(this).find("5").text();
            d6 = $(this).find("6").text();
            d7 = $(this).find("7").text();
            d8 = $(this).find("8").text();
            d1Post = $(this).find("1").attr("post"); 

            // Build row HTML data and store in string
            mydata = BuildStudentHTML(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d1Post);
            myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
        });
        myHTMLOutput += '</table>';
```

The output produces a blank table with the headers 1, 2, 3, .., 8. I cannot find my error. I know this code works because it was an example from http://www.compoc.com/tuts/. When I modified it to work with my XML doc, something broke. It looks like something is wrong with the line

```
$('TextLine1',xml).each(function(i)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? This is my first time working with jquery...

Comment: If I stick **alert("this code runs");** after the line
**$('TextLine1',xml).each(function(i){** I will receive no output. But if I stick it before that line, I will see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your XML is not valid. The problem appears to be that you are naming tags with numbers. If I change your XML to look like the following then it works fine:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>
<E1TC NAME='R584211WXB' VERSION='a'>
<TextLine1>
    <a>2011/11/06</a>
    <b>5748283</b>
    <c>10.9300</c>
    <d>4049027</d>
    <e>7.7000</e>
    <f>42799422</f>
    <g>81.3800</g>
    <h>52596733</h>
</TextLine1>
</E1TC>
```

I used this website to validate your XML: http://xmlgrid.net/

Here is a demo of the above XML: http://jsfiddle.net/cHA4D/

Comment: Thank you for the great resource and answer!